# Elasticsearch Thrift client time-out

Tags: python, sockets, elasticsearch, thrift, socket-timeout-exception

Sorry for cross posting.The following question is also posted on Elastic Search's google group.

I am trying to index some documents in elasticsearch 1.2.0 using thrift connection in python client on my virtual machine. But after indexing around 1200~1800 documents I am getting a TSocket timeout. Here is the traceback -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new_insert_bulk.py", line 400, in <module>
    actions = define_products(namespace_id, store_ids, int(sys.argv[3]), category_ids, category_names, actions, cluster_id)
  File "new_insert_bulk.py", line 371, in define_products
    print helpers.bulk(es, actions)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/elasticsearch/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers.py", line 148, in bulk
    for ok, item in streaming_bulk(client, actions, **kwargs):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/elasticsearch/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers.py", line 107, in streaming_bulk
    resp = client.bulk(bulk_actions, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/elasticsearch/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 70, in _wrapped
    return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/elasticsearch/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py", line 568, in bulk
    params=params, body=self._bulk_body(body))
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/elasticsearch/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 274, in perform_request
    status, headers, data = connection.perform_request(method, url, params, body, ignore=ignore)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/elasticsearch/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/thrift.py", line 62, in perform_request
    response = tclient.execute(request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/elasticsearch/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/esthrift/Rest.py", line 42, in execute
    return self.recv_execute()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/elasticsearch/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/esthrift/Rest.py", line 53, in recv_execute
    (fname, mtype, rseqid) = self._iprot.readMessageBegin()
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.py", line 126, in readMessageBegin
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.py", line 206, in readI32
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/thrift/transport/TTransport.py", line 58, in readAll
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/thrift/transport/TTransport.py", line 159, in read
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/thrift/transport/TSocket.py", line 105, in read 
socket.timeout: timed out
```

I have attached the server logs in log2.txt. Also I have attached screenshots from bigdesk which may help. Previously, when the complexity of the documents was lower, bulk index request of around 1300 docs in each request would be indexed without any hiccups. Currently I am trying around 200 docs per request but it times out. I have kept logging level at 'TRACE'.

This chunk on the logs -

```
[2014-07-07 22:24:56,980][TRACE][lucene.iw                ] [Blaquesmith][in_0][0] elasticsearch[Blaquesmith][scheduler][T#1] DW: anyChanges? numDocsInRam=0 deletes=false hasTickets:false pendingChangesInFullFlush: false
[2014-07-07 22:24:57,277][TRACE][lucene.iw                ] [Blaquesmith][in_0][1] elasticsearch[Blaquesmith][scheduler][T#1] DW: anyChanges? numDocsInRam=0 deletes=false hasTickets:false pendingChangesInFullFlush: false
[2014-07-07 22:24:57,277][TRACE][lucene.iw                ] [Blaquesmith][in_0][1] elasticsearch[Blaquesmith][scheduler][T#1] IW: nrtIsCurrent: infoVersion matches: true; DW changes: false; BD changes: false
[2014-07-07 22:24:57,277][TRACE][lucene.iw                ] [Blaquesmith][in_0][1] elasticsearch[Blaquesmith][scheduler][T#1] DW: anyChanges? numDocsInRam=0 deletes=false hasTickets:false pendingChangesInFullFlush: false
[2014-07-07 22:24:57,496][TRACE][lucene.iw                ] [Blaquesmith][in_0][2] elasticsearch[Blaquesmith][scheduler][T#1] DW: anyChanges? numDocsInRam=0 deletes=false hasTickets:false pendingChangesInFullFlush: false
[2014-07-07 22:24:57,496][TRACE][lucene.iw                ] [Blaquesmith][in_0][2] elasticsearch[Blaquesmith][scheduler][T#1] IW: nrtIsCurrent: infoVersion matches: true; DW changes: false; BD changes: false
[2014-07-07 22:24:57,496][TRACE][lucene.iw                ] [Blaquesmith][in_0][2] elasticsearch[Blaquesmith][scheduler][T#1] DW: anyChanges? numDocsInRam=0 deletes=false hasTickets:false pendingChangesInFullFlush: false
[2014-07-07 22:24:57,980][TRACE][lucene.iw                ] [Blaquesmith][in_0][0] elasticsearch[Blaquesmith][scheduler][T#1] DW: anyChanges? numDocsInRam=0 deletes=false hasTickets:false pendingChangesInFullFlush: false
[2014-07-07 22:24:57,981][TRACE][lucene.iw                ] [Blaquesmith][in_0][0] elasticsearch[Blaquesmith][scheduler][T#1] IW: nrtIsCurrent: infoVersion matches: true; DW changes: false; BD changes: false
[2014-07-07 22:24:57,981][TRACE][lucene.iw                ] [Blaquesmith][in_0][0] elasticsearch[Blaquesmith][scheduler][T#1] DW: anyChanges? numDocsInRam=0 deletes=false hasTickets:false pendingChangesInFullFlush: false
```

keeps repeating even after a long time after the timeout. The timed-out indexing request was around 22:21:00. I dont think the document may be invalid (with the mapping or something) because I am indexing the same document after changing 2 fields.

How can I avoid this time-out?

What does that repeating chunk in the logs mean?

And how can I be sure that this wont happen occasionally in production system?
I would be glad for any help.

Logs and BigDesk screenshots - 
  https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7tAo_9BLHg4cjNyOTlQaDF3QjA&usp=sharing